# insert multiple tables into one table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I am a new programmer analyst. I am learning SQL and I am trying to insert data from multiple tables (all the tables have the same fields) into one large history table. Is there an easy way to do this? I have this so far but I know this is wrong:

```
Create Procedure InsertTables  
@ExistingTableName nvarchar(50) 
AS

   insert into EMF_Archive    
select      
em_Employee_ID,
em_Payroll_Unit,
em_Name,
em_Payroll_Unit_2,
em_Last_Name,
em_First_Name,
em_Middle_Initial,
em_Social_Security_No,
em_Payroll_Group,
em_Employee_Status,
em_Hire_Date,
em_Rehire_Date,
em_Adjusted_Hire_Date,
em_Birth_Date,
em_Termination_Date,
em_Organization,
em_Title,
em_Work_Comp,
em_Annual_Pay,
em_Salary_Rate,
em_Tax_Group,
em_Seniority_Date,
em_service_Years,
em_Service_Months,
em_Grade,
em_Variable_3,
em_Variable_4,
em_Standard_Hours,
em_Variable_10,
em_Variable_11,
em_Shift
from @ExistingTableName  

GO

EXEC InsertTables 'emf_payPeriod1'
```

I want to execute this several times like this:

```
EXEC InsertTables 'emf_payPeriod1'
EXEC InsertTables 'emf_payPeriod2'
EXEC InsertTables 'emf_payPeriod3'
  etc
```

etc.....

Comment: Have you tried your code?

Comment: N.B it is good practise to always [list the columns you are inserting to](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/10/bad-habits-to-kick-using-select-omitting-the-column-list). If you are just after a way to combine the data from 4 tables you could just create a view that combines the tables using `UNION ALL`? Providing you have a unique key for the view you can index it in the same way you would a table, but the view will always remain up to date, whereas a static table becomes out dated as soon as one of the underlying 4 tables is changed.

Comment: These tables have at least 200 fields, so I only selected the fields that I absolutely need. I am trying to combine more than 4 tables, there are dozens of tables I need to combine. That is why I didn't want to combine the data from these tables into one history table manually.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot pass the table name like you are trying to, you will need to use dynamic sql for this something like as follows ...

```
Create Procedure InsertTables  
@ExistingTableName nvarchar(128) 
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  DECLARE @Sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @Sql = N' INSERT INTO EMF_Archive    
            select      
            em_Employee_ID,
            em_Payroll_Unit,
            em_Name,
            em_Payroll_Unit_2,
            em_Last_Name,
            em_First_Name,
            em_Middle_Initial,
            em_Social_Security_No,
            em_Payroll_Group,
            em_Employee_Status,
            em_Hire_Date,
            em_Rehire_Date,
            em_Adjusted_Hire_Date,
            em_Birth_Date,
            em_Termination_Date,
            em_Organization,
            em_Title,
            em_Work_Comp,
            em_Annual_Pay,
            em_Salary_Rate,
            em_Tax_Group,
            em_Seniority_Date,
            em_service_Years,
            em_Service_Months,
            em_Grade,
            em_Variable_3,
            em_Variable_4,
            em_Standard_Hours,
            em_Variable_10,
            em_Variable_11,
            em_Shift
            from ' + QUOTENAME(@ExistingTableName)

   EXECUTE sp_executesql  @Sql
END

GO
```

**Execute Procedure**

Further to execute this procedure for all the tables you can execute the following query

```
--Make sure the following query is pulling all the required tables
SELECT name INTO #Tables
from sys.tables
WHERE name like 'emf_payPeriod%'

-- Now use that temp table to pass table names to your procedure
DECLARE @TableName NVARCHAR(128);

WHILE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM #Tables)
BEGIN
  SELECT TOP 1 @TableName = name FROM #Tables

  EXECUTE InsertTables @TableName

  DELETE FROM #Tables WHERE name = @TableName
END
```

Comment: Wow! I tried this solution that was posted and it worked! I cannot believe it! I have been reading up on Dynamic SQL and it still seems a little bit complicated to me. I have a lot I need to learn. I only knew how to write basic sql statements, so when I had to do this project I had no knowledge on how to create stored procedures and execute them. I hope I can learn how to write code like this. Can you explain how the 'WHILE EXISTS' part of the execution of this procedure works? What does (SELECT 1 FROM #Tables) do?

Comment: I will need to write quite a bit to explain every step what I have done here, if you google each key word that isnt making any sense to you, you will find plenty of stuff on internet. And please never copy paste solutions from here always test them before you actually execute them on your machine, and never execute any code on your server unless you are 101% what it does. To understand what I did in this above solution, start from googling `EXISTS`, WHILE LOOP, sys.tables, and at he end dynamic sql :) wish you all the best you got some reading to do now and accept the answer as it helped you:)

Comment: Not a problem glad to help.

Comment: For what its worth (which isn't a huge amount, probably a fraction of a second for such few loops), using a cursor would be much more efficient that using a temp table and while loop.